# Getting a timespan by using multiple date ranges against a main date range

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a requirement to find out a 'valid' timespan by comparing a main Start and End DateTimes with multiple 'ignore' pairs of Start and End DateTimes.

There could be any amount of these 'ignore' pairs and they can range from being between, or even completely covering the initial Start and End DateTime pairs.

Example Inputs and expected outputs are below (using simple time representations for now):

Example 1

```
Main Start: 04:00 
Main End  : 14:00 

Ignore Pair 1: 03:00 - 06:00 
Ignore Pair 2: 05:00 - 09:00 
Ignore Pair 3: 12:00 - 13:00 

Expected Result: Timespan(4 'Valid' Hours)
```

Example 2

```
Main Start: 04:00 
Main End  : 14:00 

Ignore Pair 1: 03:00 - 12:00

Expected Result: Timespan(2 'Valid' Hours)
```

Example 3

```
Main Start: 04:00 
Main End  : 14:00 

Ignore Pair 1: 03:00 - 20:00

Expected Result: Timespan(0 'Valid' Hours)
```

Example 4

```
Main Start: 04:00 
Main End  : 14:00 

Ignore Pair 1: 08:00 - 12:00

Expected Result: Timespan(6 'Valid' Hours)
```

Apologies if anything doesn't make sense, please let me know if anything needs more elaboration.

Comment: OK, what have you tried already?

Comment: First attempt was to just tum up all these 'ignore spans' at timespans, and subtract it from the main start and end spans, however this doesn't account for the possibility of 2 ignore spans actually overlapping with eachother (as seen in example 1)

Comment: Second attempt was to try and group up the ignore date pairs into non-overlapping pairs so in example 1, pair 1 and pair 2 would become 03:00 to 09:00 and then become 04:00 to 09:00 if you include the main start into that however I couldn't figure out technically how to do it (the idea is still in my head and thinking over it)

Comment: Is that always just an hours, not minutes?

Comment: I have used Hours show the examples more clearly, however they are all representing `DateTime` objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a List of the valid Ranges. It is a first simple scratch without optimization. The code should explain itself with the comments. If you want to get the amount of "valid" time, just add the ranges in the result with `Console.WriteLine("{0} valid hours", valid.Sum(r => (r.End - r.Start).TotalHours));`
It's coded under the assumption, that the ranges are validated (start < end)!

**Class for storing a time range:**

```
class TimeRange
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public TimeRange ()
    {

    }
    public TimeRange(TimeSpan todayStart, TimeSpan todayEnd)
    {
        Start = DateTime.Today + todayStart;
        End = DateTime.Today + todayEnd;
    }
}
```

**Testcode:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var main = new TimeRange(new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0));
    var except = new List<TimeRange>{
        new TimeRange(new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0)),
        new TimeRange(new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)),
        new TimeRange(new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0))
    };

    var valid = GetFreeSlots(main, except);
}
```

**Algorithm:**

```
private static List<TimeRange> GetFreeSlots(TimeRange main, List<TimeRange> except)
{
    // 1. ignore Ranges outside
    except = except.Where(e => main.Start < e.End && main.End > e.Start).ToList();

    // 2. shrink the main timerange from overlapping ranges
    while (true)
    {
        var x = except.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Start <= main.Start);
        if (x != null)
        {
            if (x.End >= main.End)
            {
                return new List<TimeRange>();
            }
            main.Start = x.End;
            except.Remove(x);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        var x = except.FirstOrDefault(e => e.End >= main.End);
        if (x != null)
        {
            main.End = x.Start;
            except.Remove(x);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    if (!except.Any())
    {
        return new List<TimeRange> { main };
    }

    // 3. add range[start main to start of the 1. exception] to the list of valid ranges and shrink the main time range to start = end of the 1. exception and go through the procedure again                      
    except.OrderBy(e => e.Start);
    var valid = new List<TimeRange>{new TimeRange{Start = main.Start, End = except[0].Start}};
    main.Start = except[0].End;
    except.RemoveAt(0);
    return valid.Union(GetFreeSlots(main, except)).ToList();
}
```